# xslt processing on select attribute on apply-templates

Tags: xslt

I have a XSLT as below and apply this xslt into the input xml[pasted below], it is working fine except one thing that need to clarify.

this is the input xml

```
<Test>
  <Experiment id='1'>
    <Dish1>
      <Conditions pressure='x' temp='y'/>
      <Measurement timeStamp='8am' reading='y'/>
    </Dish1>
    <Dish2>
      <Conditions pressure='x' temp='y'/>
      <Measurement timeStamp='8am' reading='y'/>
    </Dish2>
    <Dish1>
      <Conditions pressure='x' temp='y'/>
      <Measurement timeStamp='2pm' reading='y'/>
    </Dish1>
    <Dish2>
      <Conditions pressure='x' temp='y'/>
      <Measurement timeStamp='2pm' reading='y'/>
    </Dish2>
   </Experiment>
   <Experiment id='2'>
    <Dish1>
      <Conditions pressure='x' temp='y'/>
      <Measurement timeStamp='9am' reading='y'/>
    </Dish1>
    </Experiment>
</Test>
```

this is the xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Experiment">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
         <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="local-name()">
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />

            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Experiment/*">
      <Observation>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*/@*" />
      </Observation>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is transformation is working fine. But, if i change as below on the xslt, then, it is getting error. Any idea?

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I.e., On the last match, I have changed  from  `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` to     `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` means the current node. When you apply-templates to `.`, you're applying them to the current context.

In your case, the template will match `Test`, output a copy of it, and apply-templates to itself. It will then match again basically putting you into an endless loop.

By doing the apply-templates on `node()|@*`, you're applying templates to all child nodes and attributes.

Comment: Here, on the XSLT, i mean to say, whatever is matching currently at this template, it can be an element or attribute, for this, I am applying the `<copy>` for the same by means of `.` on `apply-templates`. I am not able to understand how it can be go of endless loop.