# XSLT what are difference between?

Tags: xslt

What is the difference between these template on the output? How will these two produce outputs? I am bit confusing to understand this

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What part of [Daniel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18447135/1078110) did you not understand? I feel he explained it well but if he didn't that would help us answer you better.

Comment: I Need some more user friendly explanation on this. From Daniel's answer, i could not make it entire things that i want to know. Thats why.

Comment: The first one applies templates to all **child nodes** while the second one applies templates to the **current node** (probably causing an infinite loop).

Comment: The second one goes into an endless loop because it "stays" at the current node. It does not "move on". While the first one "moves on" to the children of a node. Best regards, Peter